# Загрузка файла в Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel5, загрузка

Пробую загрузить файл с помощью ajax в laravel. 
Файл без ajax грузится хорошо, но вот с ним выдаёт в логах

```
status: 500
statusCode: function statusCode()
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
```

Контроллер UploadController:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class UploadController extends Controller
{

    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        foreach ($request->file() as $file) {
            foreach ($file as $f) {
                $f->move(storage_path('files'), time().'_'.$f->getClientOriginalName());
            }
        }
        return "Успех";
        //return view('page');
    }
}
```

Маршрут:

```
Route::post('upload',['as' => 'upload_file','uses' => 'UploadController@upload']);
```

Форма:

```
<div class="col-6">
    <p class="lead">Загрузка файла:</p>
    <form method="post" action="{{ route('upload_file') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputAddress" class="col-form-label">Отчёт</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" multiple name="file[]" >
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
        </div>
    </form>
<button class="btn" onclick="send()"> Обновить информацию</button>
```

AJAX

```
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function send() {
                            $.ajax({
                                url : 'upload',
                                method : 'POST',
                                dataType : 'json',
                                beforeSend: function() {
                                    $('.loader').show();
                                },
                                success : function(fssp){
                                    console.log(fssp);
                                        $("#clearrr").html(fssp.result);
                                    },
                                error: function(fssp) { 
                                    console.log(fssp); 
                                    }
                            });
                        }
                    </script>
```

в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: У вас отсутствует параметр data при формировании запроса

Comment: @КириллЖелнов а как его правильно сформировать для файла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Форма:

```
<div class="col-6">
<p class="lead">Загрузка файла:</p>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress" class="col-form-label">Отчёт</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file"  >
    <input id="upload" type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </div>
</form>
```

Обновить информацию

Скрипт:

```
$('#upload').on('click', function() {
var file_data = $('#file').prop('files')[0];
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file', file_data);
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    })
$.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            type: 'post',
             beforeSend: function() {
                                $('.loader').show();
                            },
                            success : function(fssp){
                                console.log(fssp);
                                    $("#clearrr").html(fssp.result);
                                },
                            error: function(fssp) { 
                                console.log(fssp); 
                                }
 });
 });
```

Comment: при загрузке страницы в логах - ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: и не совсем понятно откуда #upload

Comment: #upload - кнопка отправки данных. Скорее всего, у вас некорректно подключена библиотека jquery

Comment: Вот теперь понятно откуда #upload)) изначально не было

Comment: @sbaikov, всё получилось?

Comment: Выкидывает ошибку MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:  разбираюсь пока-что

Comment: Скорее всего, из-за этой строчки  url: 'upload.php', попробуйте так: url: 'upload'

Comment: Это понятно:) дело где-то в другом)

Comment: у меня так и не вышло. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Какая ошибка появляется ?

Comment: Всё та же. MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218

Comment: Решили проблему? )